# Which frameworks can I use with Google GWT for develop a web app?

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, gwt

I want to make a web application with GWT.
The application will have a access to MYSQL database for obtain users informations and other.
Which frameworks can I use with Google GWT for handle: database access, form validations, accesses control(signup, login), send of email,etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start the development you should first create an artifact. You can use:

- [gwt-maven-archetypes](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes) if you want to run your project with Jetty or Tomcat
- [gwt-maven-springboot-archetype](https://github.com/NaluKit/gwt-maven-springboot-archetype) if you prefer Spring Boot

If you do not want to create the widgets by yourself, you should take a look at [Domino-UI](https://github.com/DominoKit/domino-ui).

To communicate with the server, I would go with: [Domino-Rest](https://github.com/DominoKit/domino-rest).

For the client application I would go with [Nalu](https://github.com/NaluKit/nalu). (Disclaimer: I am the author of Nalu)

On the server side, I would go with Spring Boot. You can generate a demo project which uses SpringBoot or Tomcat/Jetty with Nalu and Domino-UI [here](http://www.mvp4g.org/boot-starter-nalu/BootStarterNalu.html).

[Here](https://github.com/TDesjardins/gwt-knowledge) you will find a lot of links about GWT development and resources.

If you have any questions, the [GWT Gitter](https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt) room is a good place to ask.